# Is this the standard definition of cumulative distribution function?

Tags: probability

A cumulative probability function is usually defined as:

$$F_X(x)=P(X\leq x)$$

But is it ever also sometimes defined as follows?
$$F_X(x)=P(X< x)$$

Is there a particular reason why the second one would be problematic, or incorrect, or less general?

Comment: Both choices are fine. According to Wikipedia, some Hungarian texts use $<$.

Comment: The choice of $<$ would be a little unintuitive in the case of a discrete distribution. Hence for uniformity, $\le$ seems more appropriate.

Comment: The second definition is widely used in Russia and the fSU. For a discrete distribution, there are some differences at 'jump points', but both definitions are equally useful.

Answer (score -1):

The 2nd definition is less general, used by some Hungarian mathematicians.

Note if you use the 1st definition, you CDF is right-continuous; if you use the 2nd definition, your CDF is left-continuous and related definition and theorem will change a little bit.

Ok, just remember use the 1st one and that CDF always right-continuous.

Comment: Use the first one, unless you live in a country where the second is  in standard use, and then remember that the CDF is always _left-continuous._

Comment: I agree using the first one. But by using definition $F_X(x) = Pr(X \leq x)$, the CDF is right-continuous.  A simple example will be, $Pr(X=1)=1$, equals 0 otherwise. So it's CDF jumps at the point 1, and is continuous when it approaches from right side.

Comment: Confused: $\le$ _is_ the first one.